wrap echo'd messages after `my:echo-max-width`
As long as (setq message-truncate-lines nil), messages with very long lines are 'wrapped' in the echo area once they would go off-screen. The wrapping seems to behave similarly to what visual-line-mode achieves in ordinary buffers.
This still allows lines in the echo area to span the full width of the frame. I find multiple short lines easier to scan and read than one extremely long line. I would like to do something like (setq my:echo-max-width 72) and have messages visually wrap onto the next line after my:echo-max-width characters.
